# Change Map of Map to generic type

Tags: java, dictionary, oop, generics, jvm

I have a method which takes a Map which has Key as String and value as an object of type T which is a serializable object.

```
public <T extends Serializable> void set(String key, Map<String, T> fields) {
  ......
  .......
}
```

When I'm trying to pass map of map, it's giving an error for wrong argument type. I want this method to take a generic object and don't want to change it to `set(String key, Map<String, Map<String, String>> fields)`

```
Map<String, String> fieldmapL1 = new HashMap<>();
fieldmapL1.put("ABC", "XYZ");
Map<String, Map<String, String>> fieldmapL2 = new HashMap<>();
fieldmapL2.put("Key", fieldmapL1);

instance.set("key", fieldmapL2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue is that you type is not matching you requirements. As explained by @Pankaj in others comments of this topic, Map is not serializable so your definition of fieldmap2 does not meet the criteria for T. Updating instantiations of maps to properly use HashMap which implements serializable do the trick (aka no more warning in intelliJ)

```
public static class Test{
        public <T extends Serializable> void set(String key, Map<String, T> fields) {

        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> fieldMapL1 = new HashMap<>();
        fieldMapL1.put("ABC", "XYZ");
        Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> fieldmap2 = new HashMap<>();
        fieldmap2.put("key", fieldMapL1);

        Test test = new Test();
        test.set("key", fieldmap2);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to indicate the type, you're using:

```
instance.<Map<String, String>>set("key", fieldmapL2);
```

Then type `T` is resolved to `String`. Also this will work only if `instance` is properly instantiated (you can set `T` to `String` on instantiation, then you don't need the above line or you can omit explicit types and use my solution).

Comment: I want type T to be resolved to `Map<String, String>` not `String`. instance is properly instantiated.

Comment: instead of <string> it should be Map<String,String> otherwise T will be of type string

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, forgot that one;)

Comment: Nope. I have already tried this. It gives same error `instance.<HashMap<String, String>>set("key", fieldmapL2);`

Comment: @Pankaj declared type of `fieldMap2` is `Map`, not `HashMap`

Comment: @Lino Map is not a serializable object. HashMap is hence used HashMap

Comment: @Pankaj how about providing the type on instantiation?

Comment: @Andronicus unfortunately, can't provide type during instantiation